# SQL syntax error on trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck in sql, anyone knows why does it point to a syntax error where it says "on"?

```
delimiter $$
use mydb $$
CREATE TRIGGER NuevaSerie ON `Mydb`.`Serie`
FOR INSERT
AS

INSERT INTO Documento
        (Serie_idSerie)
    SELECT
        idSerie
        FROM inserted
end$$
```

I am trying to create a new row in table Documento, column Serie_idSerie when someone adds a new row to Serie. Thank you.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax does not correspond to any database.  It is a weird mixture of MySQL and SQL Server.

In MySQL, the trigger syntax would look like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER NuevaSerie AFTER INSERT ON `Mydb`.`Serie`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Documento (Serie_idSerie)
       VALUES (new.idSerie);
END$$
```